# Does editing a state variable requires 2 database access

Tags: solidity

Hi I am fairly new to solidity. Consider this snippet

```
// state variable
mapping(address => uint) deposits;
function deposit() public {
    // using OpenZeppelin SafeMath add
    deposits[msg.sender] = deposits[msg.sender].add(amount);
}
```

Does this require one DB read to fetch `deposit[msg.sender]` and one DB write to change
its value?
This will have any benefits over `deposits[msg.sender] += amount` (i.e. does this require
only one DB access?)

Comment: I know that starting from solidity >= 0.8 `add` and `+` should be equivalent in terms of dealing with overflow

Comment: Read on the right, write on the left. `+=` will do the same.  Agree with @mr_bovo. There is no benefit to using the SafeMath `.add()` method after `0.8.x` It is more efficient not to and more readable, IMHO. I would write `deposits[msg.sender] += amount`